# Chicken or Egg paradox with type and object in Python

Tags: python, object, types, instance, subclass

I remembered learning that `type` is its own instance and that all new-style classes inherit from `object`, so I started messing around:

```
issubclass(type, object) # True
issubclass(object, type) # False
# issubclass(cls, cls) is always True
type(type) is type # True
type(object) is type # True
```

To sum that up in words, `type` like any new-style class is a subclass of `object`, and like any class, both `type` and `object` are instances of `type`. Here's a handy picture:

[image: Picture of relationship between type and object in Python]

Big disclaimer here that I'm not a programmer and know little about the underlying mechanics of Python, so bear with me if I sound dumb. Normally a class has to be made before its instances. However, a superclass normally has to be made before its subclass. Applying those general Python rules to `type` and `object` makes an apparent chicken-egg paradox.

So which of these classes are made first? I also suspect that because these classes are implemented in a lower-level language, they don't have to follow Python rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python)

Comment: That post has a lot of explanation of what a metaclass is (with `type` being the primordial metaclass), but I don't quite see where it answers my question of how the `type` class can inherit from its own instance `object` when Python usually enforces object creation order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a language semantics perspective, both `type` and `object` exist, fully initialized, from the moment the program begins. Whatever the implementation does to get things into that state doesn't have to follow the rules of what the implementation allows *you* to do.

From a CPython implementation perspective, both `type` and `object` are statically allocated at C level, and neither is created first. You can see the variable definitions in `Objects/typeobject.c`. [Here's `object`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Objects/typeobject.c#L4727):

```c
PyTypeObject PyBaseObject_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "object",                                   /* tp_name */
    sizeof(PyObject),                           /* tp_basicsize */
    0,                                          /* tp_itemsize */
    object_dealloc,                             /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                                          /* tp_print */
    0,                                          /* tp_getattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_reserved */
    object_repr,                                /* tp_repr */
    ...
};
```

and [here's `type`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Objects/typeobject.c#L3553):

```c
PyTypeObject PyType_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "type",                                     /* tp_name */
    sizeof(PyHeapTypeObject),                   /* tp_basicsize */
    sizeof(PyMemberDef),                        /* tp_itemsize */
    (destructor)type_dealloc,                   /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                                          /* tp_print */
    0,                                          /* tp_getattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_setattr */
    0,                                          /* tp_reserved */
    (reprfunc)type_repr,                        /* tp_repr */
    ...
};
```

When interpreter initialization begins, both `type` and `object` are in a half-initialized state, and the `PyType_Ready` function is responsible for finishing their initialization. The type pointers are set up in the variable definitions, but setting the superclass pointers is part of `PyType_Ready`'s job, and plenty of other initialization needs to be handled by `PyType_Ready` - for example, the types don't have a `__dict__` yet.

Incidentally, using some weird metaclasses and the fact that Python allows you to reassign `__class__` on instances of user-defined classes, [we can set up our own classes](https://ideone.com/GoceSf) `A` and `B` where `B` is a subclass of `A` and both `A` and `B` are instances of `B`, much like the situation with `object` and `type`. This is nothing like how `object` and `type` are actually created, though:

```py
class DummyMeta(type):
    pass

class A(type, metaclass=DummyMeta):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

B.__class__ = B
A.__class__ = B

print(isinstance(A, B))
print(isinstance(B, B))
print(issubclass(B, A))
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
```

Comment: holy cow Python actually gives you a way to reassign `__class__` for classes, that looks so messed up

Comment: @BatWannaBe: It is really weird and almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, everything is an object:

- `7` is an object of type `int`.
- `'foo'` is an object of type `str`.
- `None` is an object of type `NoneType`.
- If you define a class `class Foo: pass`, then `Foo` is an object of type `class`. And any object `Foo()` that you construct from that class is an object of type `Foo`.
- If you define a function as `def f(x): pass,` that function itself is an object.

Every object has a type. But what is a type? That's right--even *types themselves* are objects with the type `type`.

```py
issubclass(type, object) # True
issubclass(object, type) # False
```

Every class is a subclass of `object`, by definition. The `object` class is not a subclass of anything; it's the root of all "objecthood". It follows that `isinstance(o, object)` always returns `True`.

```py
type(type) is type # True
type(object) is type # True
```

We know that everything in python is an instance of `object`. But what about the `object` class itself? It's an object too. What kind of object? `object` is a type, just like `int`, `str`, or `function`. Thus the type of `object` is `type`. However, any *instance* of the `object` class is not a type, but merely an object:

```
type(object()) is object # True
```

In summary, Everything is an object, even the types of other objects.

To give a non-answer the "which comes first" question, it doesn't really matter; these things are abstractions anyway and so you can make a language with whatever semantics you feel like defining, and there's nothing wrong with "cycles".

To give a more concrete answer, if you are interested in the implementation, it looks like the typedef for c-level `PyObject`s (which become `object`) in the [source code for CPython here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aacc77fbd77640a8f03638216fa09372cc21673d/Include/cpython/object.h), and compare to the typedef for `PyTypeObject` in the same file.

Edit: The other answer better explains the CPython implementation.